# Net Promoter Score Calculation Formula?

Tags: admin

I am dealing with survey responses through Survey Force and with that I am trying to Capture the true Net Promoter Score (which is Promoter - Detractors).

Promoter is any response = 9,10
Passive is any response = 7,8
Detractor is any response <= 6

I currently created a custom field Named Category | data type: formula and named it category to distinguish the responses into those three categories for reporting purposes. This worked perfect in how I wanted it. (below is the formula and workflow I used)

Evaluation Criteria:Created and every time is edited
Rule Criteria:Formula evaluates to TRUE and the formula is

**NOT(ISBLANK(Response__c))**

Immediate Action: Field Update
Field to Update: Category
Specify a formula to set the new value and the formula is

**IF(
VALUE(Response__c) <= 6, "Detractor",
IF(
VALUE(Response__c) <= 8, "Passive",
"Promoter"
)
)**

I then created a Custom summary formula to capture the percentage of all three categories which worked perfectly. (Below is the formula and graph of how is shows)

**RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)**

[image]

What I Don't know how to do is create another summary formula to just extract the Promoter % and the Detractor % to then SUBTRACT those two to just show one % BAR instead of three as in the picture. I manually do the calculation and just have it up in the header but with it constantly changing I can't update it all the time.  I need real time feed in the chart.  PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: If you used a picklist field instead of a formula field, and then a workflow to populate that picklist on edit, you could roll up the response counts for each category to the parent survey record. These rollups could then be used in report formulas to calculate your percentages.

Another (simpler) option if you write apex code would be a simple trigger to maintain the percentages for you on the parent survey record each time a response was added, changed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for the benefit of others who may encounter similar as the OP, my solution to this was to create a formula field : `IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Response__c)),VALUE(Response__c) > 8), 1, 
IF(AND( NOT(ISBLANK(Response__c)) ,VALUE(Response__c) < 6) , -1, 0) 
)` And then in my report I created a grand summary custom formula in the form`( SurveyObject__c.myformulafield__c:SUM / RowCount )` This gave me exactly what I needed.